# Mal funcionamiento de pipe, fork

Tags: c, proceso

Estoy estudiando cómo hacer tuberías a procesos hijos; he escrito este código de prueba que crea una serie de hijos(4 en este ejemplo), y abre tuberías entre ellos y el proceso padre (al menos eso querría yo):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int Prueba(int N);



int main()
{

    printf("%d\t",1); //Salida rara
    //printf("%d\n",1); //Salida "esperada"

    Prueba(4); 

    return 0;
}


int Prueba(int N)
{
    int i,j;
    int ind_hijo;
    int pid_padre, *pid_hijo, **tuberia;


    pid_hijo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    tuberia = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
    tuberia = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        tuberia[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);



    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        pid_hijo[i]=-1;  //Inicializo el array de hijos

    pid_padre = getpid();


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {

        if(getpid() == pid_padre) //El padre (y solo el padre) crea hijos
        {
            pipe(tuberia[i]); //Se abren dos descriptores de archivo por cada hijo que se va a crear
            pid_hijo[i]=fork(); //Se crea el i-esimo hijo
            if(pid_hijo[i] == 0)
            {
                pid_padre = -1; //De este modo se distingue a los hijos del padre rapidamente

                close(tuberia[i][0]); //Cada hijo cierra el extremo de lectura de su tubo...
            }
            close(tuberia[i][1]); //... y el padre cierra los extremos de escritura de sus tubos
        }
    }


    if(pid_padre == -1)
    {
        //... Codigo  ...

        exit(0); //se cierra cada proceso hijo
    }




    while(wait(NULL)>0); //El padre espera a que todos los hijos esten cerrados



    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        close(tuberia[i][0]); //El padre cierra los descriptores de archivo abiertos (esto es necesario??)


    return 0;

}
```

El programa en sí no hace nada, solo crea los hijos para luego cerrarlos y  escribe un símbolo (un "1"). Yo esperaba que ese "1" se escribiera una sola vez (y así es si lo escribo con "\n"). Sin embargo, con la linea

```
printf("%d\t",1);
```

resulta que la salida en la terminal es:

```
1    1    1    1    1
```

He hecho pruebas con otro número de hijos, y la salida siempre es el nº de hijos +1. No entiendo nada de lo qué está pasando aquí.

Comment: He corregido pequeños errores en el código (consecuencia de haber simplificado el código original para formular esta pregunta, lo siento). Esas correcciones no afectan al problema que describo (la pregunta sigue en pie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando llamas a `fork` se hace una copia completa de toda la memoria del proceso actual y dicha copia se le asigna al nuevo proceso. Esta copia incluye, como no podía ser de otra forma, tanto el buffer de salida como el de entrada.

Cuando tu llamas a `printf` el texto no se vuelca inmediatamente a la consola sino que se acumula en el buffer de salida hasta que se realiza una llamada implícita o explícita a `fflush`.

Un ejemplo de llamada implícita a `fflush` se realiza al llamar a funciones de entrada tipo `scanf`:

```
printf("Hola, dime tu nombre: ");
scanf("%s,nombre);
```

En este caso vamos a ver siempre el mensaje porque `scanf` realiza de forma implícita una llamada a `fflush`.

Puedes verificar este extremo forzando una llamada a `fflush`. Entonces verás como el mensaje aparece una sola vez:

```
printf("%d\t",1); //Salida rara
fflush(stdout);
```

Aunque, por otro lado, hay formas más limpias de imprimir un 1 en pantalla:

```
printf("1\t");
```

O mejor aun

```
puts("1\t");
```